# How to add a nav bar at the bottom of a view programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have a view with a nav bar on top (I downloaded this app and its a nav controller app) but how to add a nav bar on bottom?

Comment: Are you sure that is a Navigation bar ? Might be a custom view bar.

Comment: well im pretty sure it is, i want to add one to the bottom of my view.

Comment: It's called toolbar in that context.

Comment: ok then i want a toolbar! thanks for helping me with the terms :D and does anyone know what to add for the code? because i have        UINavigationBar * nav = [[UINavigationBar alloc]init];     [self.view addSubView:nav];   and this isnt working i put it in the viewDidLoad: method.

Answer (score 1):

//

modified

```
UINavigationBar *bottomBar=[[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 436, 320, 44)];

[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460-44)];

[self.view addSubview:bottomBar];
```

Comment: ok this works but it takes my Navigation bar at the top and puts its to the bottom, that is where i want it, but i want a total of two bars in the whole view!

Comment: ok perfect, the only thing that doesnt work on this is that the bar is stuck to my tableView. So when i scroll it is moving with the tableView :( p.s. im sorry i keep asking questions im just really new to this i know obj c but i usually use interface Builder!

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the UINavigationController actually supports this out of the box. It's called a UIToolbar, I believe and if you look in the documentation, you'll be able to find more on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can able to use the UItoolbar instead of navigation bar

```
     UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWith:CGRectMake(0, 436, 320, 44)];

    [myview addSubview:toobar];
```

Comment: Hey man thanks a lot for the help i really appreciate it!!! But this code adds the toolbar to my tableView and i have to scroll the tableView up to see it, do you know what im doing wrong?? Thanks man

Comment: ok i have one more question. im sorry! i added a .xib file with the .h & .m files and i added an outlet and connected it to my toolBar. Then i went into my main viewController and added                ToolBar * obj = [[ToolBar alloc]init];
    
    [self.view addSubview:obj.bottomBar]; into my viewDidLoad: method but nothing is showing up what am i doing wrong???

Comment: decrease your uitableview height